# Using the indefinite article with a category name

Tags: word-usage, indefinite-article

In Italian, I would say *non puoi usare "muro" come aggettivo* (literally, "you can't use *wall* as adjective").

Should I use the indefinite article before *adjective* in that case, or is the sentence correct/understood even without it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use the indefinite article in the sentence *You can't use **wall** as **an** adjective*. It's ungrammatical in English without the article. Of course the sentence will be understood without the article, but it's incorrect without it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, in English any time you use a singular noun you must put either an article , a possessive adjective (e.g. "my"), or an adjective meaning "none" or "one" or a similar idea in front of it. (There may be some other adjectives that would work, though I can't think of one at the moment.)

"I saw a dog."

"I saw the dog."

"I saw your dog."

"I saw one dog."

"I saw no dog."

"I saw some dog."

WRONG: "I saw dog." No adjective.

WRONG: "I saw blue dog." "Blue" is an adjective but doesn't indicate possession or number, you still need another adjective. Like, "I saw the blue dog."